# Java method that takes only objects that inherit from super class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, typed

I would like to have a method in a Java class that will allow me to pass only objects that inherit from super class, f.e.:

I have container super class `Div`:

```
package org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.html;
    public class Div extends ComplexWidget {
        public Div() {
            setElement(Document.get().createDivElement());
        }
    }
```

I would like to use `Div` class and its children in the `NRowsXNColumns` class:

```
public class NRowsXNColumns extends GenericLayout {
    public NRowsXNColumns(List<T extends Div> containers) {
        // Do something with each container that extends Div class
        for(T extends Div container: containers) {
            container.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't compile.

Comment: What is your compilation error?

Comment: Clearly, `T extends Div` is not valid Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict types in generics, such as declaring a `List<? extends Div>`, but you cannot use that notation when declaring the loop variable `container`:

```
for (Div container : containers) {
    container.display();
}
```

Since all the objects in `containers` must be `Div` or a subclass of `Div`, they can all be assigned to a variable declared simply as a `Div`.

(In a generic method, you can define `<T extends Div>` and then declare the list as `List<T extends Div>`, but there's no such definition of `T` present in this case.)

Comment: Ok. Loop clarification is great. But declaration You gave me dosn't compile, I am getting an error: `Syntax error on token "extends", , expected` and `The type parameter Div is hiding the type Div`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I copied the `T extends Div` from your code, and didn't realize that `T` wasn't defined there. You can use a `?` wildcard in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
class NRowsXNColumns extends GenericLayout {
    public <T extends Div> NRowsXNColumns(List<T> containers) {
        for(T container: containers) {
            // Do whatever with container
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work. My class `NRowsXNColumns` dosen't  takes any Typed argument T. Additionaly You haven't limit arguments to classes that extends SuperClass `Div`. In Your example it can takes everything, as I understood it. I don't understand also why You did add return type?

Comment: Hmmm. Did you try it? If not suggest to try it. Generics dont need to be defined at class level. They can as well declared be at constructor or method level too. What you see between <> is NOT a return type. But a way to specify the generic type information. In the code snippet, we are specifying that the list of T must be a list of objects-that-extends-Div.

Comment: @masterdany88 `<T extends Div>` in this code constrains `T` just like you wanted. Only it doesn't really buy much, a wildcard would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just -

```
public NRowsXNColumns(List<Div> containers) {
```

Now you can pass a list of objects which are of Div class or any subclass of Div

Comment: Unless the list you are passing was declared as `List<Div>`, this won't work.

Comment: OP wants to pass a list of objects of div or subclass of div. So how else he will declare that list if not `List<Div>`. What are saying is correct. But how does that make this answer incorrect?

Comment: If there is a subclass called `FloatedDiv`, it is entirely possible that somewhere there is a `List<FloatedDiv>` in OP's code, and that list could not be passed to this method.

Comment: That doesn't make sense because he want to pass list of any subclass of Div and/or the Div itself. Why would he create List<FloatedDiv> in that case.

Comment: If he is already creating a `List<FloatedDiv>` for some other reason elsewhere in the code. It isn't necessarily a list that was created *solely to pass to this method*.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava there is a concept called invariance in case of List of generics. What it means is that List<DivSubClass> can not be passed when the method takes List<Div>. Suggest to relook.